# Java linkedlist - How to copy data?

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I'm trying to code a function that moves 'n' amount of nodes in a doubly linkedlist from the front and adds them to the back:

```
public class PetList {
    protected class LinkNode {
        protected LinkNode next;
        protected LinkNode prev;
        protected Pet animal; // note that my data within a node is an object

        public LinkNode() {
            next = prev = null;
        }
    }
    protected LinkNode first;
    protected LinkNode last;

    public PetList() {
        first = last = null;
    }
//...
//... other functions

public void Rotate(int n) {

}
```

Now I know how to insert a node to the rear, for example:

```
public void insertRear(Pet giraffe) {
    LinkNode temp = new LinkNode();
    temp.animal = new Pet(giraffe);
    if(first == null) {
        first = last = temp;
        return;
    }
    temp.prev = last;
    last.next = temp;
    last = temp;
}
```

But in my Rotate function:

```
public void Rotate(int n)
```

I don't have an object as the parameter. That is, how can I create a temp LinkNode and copy the data in the object of the first LinkNode, then move my temp Node to the back, the delete my first node? Or is there another better way of doing this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Moving data is different from copying data

Comment: Why would you need an object as a parameter?  You already said that you just want to move the first thing in the list to the end.

Comment: take the first node, remove it, mark the next node as the new head of the list, then put your first node at the end.

Comment: to extend @njzk2 answer, make `Rotate` recursive.

Comment: Why do you want to create new nodes and copy the data? You can just move the existing nodes, and the data will follow automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty simple. Here is how you move one node from the head to the tail:

```
public void moveHeadToTail() {
    if (first == null || last == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("can't do that on empty list");
    }
    // Detach the first node
    LinkNode temp = first;
    first = temp.next;
    first.previous = null;
    temp.next = null;

    // Put the tmp node at the end
    last.next = temp;
    temp.prev = last;
    last = temp;
}
```

Then, you can split that into better functions: `popHead` and `pushTail`:

```
public LinkNode popHead() {
    if (first == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("can't do that on empty list");
    }
    LinkNode temp = first;
    first = temp.next;
    first.previous = null;
    temp.next = null;
    return temp;
}

public void pushTail(LinkNode node) {
    if (last == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("can't do that on empty list");
    }
    last.next = node;
    node.prev = last;
    node.next = null;
    last = node;
}
```

Which then makes the rotation easier:

```
public void moveHeadToTail() {
    pushTail(popHead());
}
```

Then the modification to get that to work for `n` should be fairly trivial.

Comment: You could do the update (not counting traversal) in O(1) by moving the entire block at once.

Comment: "(not counting traversal)" why not count traversal?

Comment: You'll still need to traverse n elements to find the cutoff, but you don't need to update each one.

Comment: @shmosel but how can you consider measuring your complexity by excluding some of the operations?

Comment: (what I mean is that, yes, it would be more efficient, but it wouldn't change the complexity.)

Comment: That's not correct. I'm not sure why you think complexity can't be calculated separately for separate operations. See for example [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-) javadoc.

Comment: The complexity of "rotating n elements from head to tail" is O(n). Because it requires the traversal. If you already know the nth node, then yes, the complexity of "moving head..node x to tail" is O(1), but that's not the question, and to know node x, you need to traverse, which is O(n).

Comment: I'm not going to pursue a debate over terminology. Are we agreed on my point that there's room for significant performance improvement?

Comment: @shmosel performance and complexity are not the same thing. I think I may have pointed that already. As a side note, based on the code I wrote, there are several ways of getting to the OP's final goal. A trivial way is to put all of that in a loop. A sligthly more subtle way is to return a list instead of a single node from the `popHead`, and have `pushTail` take a list in parameter. I haven't specified which one should be used. So I don't really see where, in the current state of things, you want to improve.

Comment: I never said they're the same thing, and I stand by my statement that the time complexity can be improved by using a single pop operation, the end goal being, of course, an improvement in performance. I understood that you were suggesting calling `pushTail(popHead())` in a loop, but I see now that it could also be interpreted as per my approach.

Comment: "time complexity can be improved by using a single pop operation". No. The performance would be better, certainly, but the time complexity of the rotate operation is still O(n), since that operation includes the initial traversal, which is O(n) for this data structure.

Comment: You keep repeating that point, but there's no basis to it. Traversal and modification are two separate operations that each have their own time complexity. You don't *have to* evaluate them together just because they're happening in the same process. See my proof above.

Comment: but you can't do the modification if you don't have the traversal before, can you?

Comment: Correct. You also can't binary search an unsorted array.

Answer (score 1):

I would chop off a piece of length `n` nodes from the start of the list, keeping track of both the first and the last node in the chopped off list. Set `first` to the node following the chopped off sublist to make it the new first node. Then I would append the sublist to the end by providing links both ways between the old last node and the first node in the sublist. Finally set `last` to the end of the sublist, and I’d be done.

Draw your nodes as boxes on paper and the links as arrows to other boxes. Wipe out and draw to visualize the steps. Then it should all be clearer.